# default activerecord store session timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, activerecord, session-state, session-timeout

Can someone tell me what the default timeout is when using `activeRecord` store?

I don't want to 'set' the timeout because I want it to behave as a session cookie.
ie: expire when the user closes the browser, which doesn't happen if you manually set the expire date.

When I leave the expire date off, the session will timeout sometime within a couple of hours of no use. Why is this so?

So really what I'm asking is, is it possible for the session to not timeout at all when the user keeps his/her browser open and only expire when he/she hits logout or closes the browser?
Keeping in mind:

the cookie doesn't get deleted if you specify an expiration on the `activeRecord` `session_store` when user closes browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is two points here, Session Timeout and Page/HTTP Timeout from Web Server.

As far as I understand, ActiveRecord Store Session store doesn't timeout, unless the user moves away from the page.

Alternatively, if the Web Server decides after sufficient time of idle-ness to then drop the connection, which in turn negates the Sessions.